# How to get data from fitbit using PHP

Tags: php, fitbit

I'm trying to get user data from fitbit using fitbit api but the process seems confusing to me. I have tried several ways but could not succeed. I have searched in the internet for solution and found this
http://www.staze.org/retrieving-steps-data-fitbit-api/
But this process is also not working for me.
How to fix the code I mentioned to get data from fitbit or is there any other way to get data using PHP?

Comment: "But this process is also not working for me. " — You need to provide a [mcve] and a **clear problem statement**. "Not working" is very vague. What result did you get? What result did you expect? What did you do to debug it to trace the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do lot of homwwork Dude ;)  Anyways...

To access Fitbit Data you can use **OAuth 2.0** authentication

You need to pass **tokenType** and **accessCode** in any ajax call and you will get response

Now to get accessCode you need to register an App on [Fitbit](https://dev.fitbit.com/apps/oauthinteractivetutorial) site

You can read [API doc](https://dev.fitbit.com/reference/#overview) for more details

Here is sample code how to access Fitbit Profile using tokenType and accessCode 
 and I can assure you this is working Code so if your code doesnt work 
 it means you are doing somthing wrong in above steps

```
function getProfile() {
    var authCode = token_type + " " + access_token;
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/profile.json",
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", fitbitAccessCode);
        },
        success: function(jsonObject) {
            // logic ...
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That's JavaScript. The question is asking about PHP.

Comment: I am also using php along with jquery so thought it would help .. Anyways his question is very Broad... Surely doesn't deserve down vote ...

Comment: There is no PHP in your answer.

Comment: If the question is too broad (which it is) then vote to close it as off-topic instead of providing a bad answer.